# Crear archivo en base a dos listas que contengan un campo igual Python

Tags: python

Necesito crear un archivo de salida en base a dos listas. En estas listas tengo un campo en común con el que me apoyo para unir ambas listas, es decir:

```
lista1= [("1","005789","A","LM3P"),("1","005789","C","NON"),("2","005790","B","LM4P"),]

lista2= [("52061","005789","190233","19:04:18","AA","O","MD_NA"),("52063","005790","190233","16:05:13","CC","O","MD_NA"),]
```

El segundo campo en ambas listas es mi identificador y mi campo en común, los demás son información del registro.

Debo crear una tercera lista en la cual tenga unidas ambas listas en base a mi campo identificador, es decir, si lista1[1] == lista2[1] entonces une ambos registros de las listas. 
¿Cómo hago que por cada registro de la lista2, busque si existe "identificador" en la lista1 y me una la información? También puedo tener varios registros con un mismo número "identificador" en mi lista 1, pero al final en la lista3 a crear solo debe haber un registro de ese id pero con la información completa...

Comment: ¿Qué pasa con los registros repetidos en `lista1`?¿Se escoge el primero de ellos?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: ChemaCortes, debo añadir los campos lista1[2] y lista1[3] al final del registro. gracias por la ayuda..

Comment: Por favor, Yaz, para evitar ambigüedades, añade el resultado concreto que esperas a partir del ejemplo que has puesto.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que propones de iterar por `lista1` y para cada valor buscar en `lista2` no es muy eficiente, ya que estarás recorriendo la `lista2` completa por cada elemento de `lista1`. El número de iteraciones total sería `N*M`, siendo `N` el tamaño de `lista1` y `M` el tamaño de `lista2`.

Propongo otra solución. Recorremos `lista1 + lista2` y vamos actualizando un diccionario en el que cada clave sea el identificador (sacado del elemento) y el valor sea una lista, que contendrá todos las tuplas en las que ese sea el identificador. El número de iteraciones en esta ocasión sería `N+M`.

Es decir:

```
diccionario = {}

for dato in lista1+lista2:
  id = dato[1]
  if id not in diccionario:
    diccionario[id] = []
  diccionario[id].append(dato)
```

Al terminar tendrás un diccionario que ha "agrupado" en la misma clave los valores que haya encontrado en ambas listas. En este caso sale:

```
{'005789': [('1', '005789', 'A', 'LM3P'),
  ('1', '005789', 'C', 'NON'),
  ('52061', '005789', '190233', '19:04:18', 'AA', 'O', 'MD_NA')],
 '005790': [('2', '005790', 'B', 'LM4P'),
  ('52063', '005790', '190233', '16:05:13', 'CC', 'O', 'MD_NA')]}
```

Después ya lo puedes procesar como quieras, por ejemplo para generar la lista "mezcla" que necesitabas (para esto habrá otro bucle con `K` iteraciones, siendo `K` el tamaño del diccionario que sería menor a `N+M`).

No tengo muy claro cómo quieres mezclar, por lo que de momento no hago esta parte.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu sugerencia, la voy a intentar y te comento... creo que como dices es mucho mas eficiente :) .. la forma en que al final debe "mezclarse" o el registro final debería de quedar así: lista3 = [lista2[0], id, lista2[2], lista2[3] ,lista2[4], lista2[5], lista2[6], lista1[0], lista1[2], lista1[3]] ese sería el formato del registro.

Comment: ¿y qué haces con los elementos que estaban repetidos en `lista1`? ¿Cómo los mezclas?

Answer (score 0):

De `lista2` creamos un diccionario con el identficador como clave:

```
res = { x[1]: x for x in lista2 }
```

Y le añadimos los elementos de `lista1`:

```
for y in lista1:
    k = y[1]
    if k in res:
        res[k] += y
```

Y luego volver a convertirlo en lista:

```
lst = list(res.values())
```

Pero se puede hacer también de modo directo en una línea, aunque menos eficiente:

```
res = [x + tuple(y for y in lista1 if x[1]==y[1])
       for x in lista2]
```

---

**Editado**

Parece ser que lo que se espera es modificar la `lista2` añadiendo los elemento de la `lista1` coincidentes. No es recomendable alterar listas dentro de un bucle, pero esta solución funcionaría:

```
for i, it2 in enumerate(lista2):
    for it1 in lista1:
        if it1[1] == it2[1]:
            lista2[i] += it1[0:1] + it1[2:]
```

`enumerate` ofrece parejas con los items de la lista y su índice. Vamos comprobando si en la lista `lista1` tenemos coincidencias y las vamos añadiendo a `lista2`.

Comment: gracias Chema por tu sugerencia, pero intentando la primera forma, solo me da como resultado los valores de la lista2, no me esta insertando los de la lista 1.. como hago para que me inserta ambas?..

Comment: A mi me funciona correctamente, aunque puede que no te hayas explicado bien. En la pregunta original deberías añadir qué resultado esperas obtener para hacernos una idea más precisa.

Comment: Hola Chema, perdón que apenas contesto... Lo que necesito que me quede al final por cada registro sería así:
Por cada registro de Lista 2, me busque los resultados que sean igual en "identificador (cuenta)" y agregue la información de ambas listas:

52061|005789|190233|19:04:18|AA|O|MD_NA|1|A|LM3P|1|C|NON -- de esta cuenta  "005789", tengo dos registros en la lista1 y las debo agregar al final
52063|005790|190233|16:05:13|CC|O|MD_NA|2|B|LM4P -- de esta cuenta "005790", solo tengo un renglon en lista1 igual agrego la información al final. Esto es lo que debo tener como archivo de salida.

Comment: De acuerdo, @YazLara. Este comentario úsalo mejor para completar la pregunta (edítala y añade este resultado esperado). Por mi parte, edito la respuesta.